# En que me equivoqué? botón de sumar en html y js

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo el siguiente código, cumple con lo que quiero de sumar, pero al momento de darle click el botón se borra.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function sumar(){
            var x = 0;
            var pi = x++;
            document.write(x);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h6 id="num1"> </h6>
        <input type="button" id="boton" value="calcular" onclick="sumar()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se te borra el botón porque al hacer `document.write` estás sobreescribiendo todo lo que hay dentro del `<body>`. Si quieres que el botón permanezca visible lo que haría sería prepara un área donde escribir la respuesta de la función para posteriormente inyectarla dentro en el DOM. Para ello puedes usar un `<p>` y la función `innerText`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function sumar(){
            var x = 0;
            var pi = x++;
            document.getElementById('respuesta').innerText = x;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h6 id="num1"> </h6>
        <input type="button" id="boton" value="calcular" onclick="sumar()">
        <p id="respuesta"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya veo , muchas gracias!